# What does the word 「よいな」 mean in this sentence?

Tags: words, colloquial-language, video-games

It was said by an old man to a boy named 'X', for example, that he would be waiting for him at a kind of vehicle.

> わしは天の箱舟で待っておる。　じゅんびがすんだら お前も来い。　**よいな**　Xよ！

If it means 'good', I think it looks not make sense to me.

Does it possibly mean 'all right' and it is followed by な particle for emphasizing?

Answer (score 1):

よいな (or in more common forms いいな, いいですね), in this case, is essentially a pretty forceful way of confirming the interlocutor has understood something - 'You've got that, haven't you?!' or something like it. The な or ね here is in its confirmation function, '- right?'.

'I shall be waiting at the Ark of Heaven. You must come too, when you are ready. You understand, X?'